# Bootstrap, BEM, and React components

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bem

Working on a react app, which has many components, each component has it's own scss files.

```
list.jsx
list.scss
module.jsx
module.scss
```

I want to use Bootstrap (because I don't want to rewrite dropdowns, and modals).
I also want to be able to override Bootstrap variables so the sass is setup like so:

```
my-variables.scss
variables.scss
bootstrap.scss
```

This works great until you get to BEM. The project uses BEM so instead of bootstrap classes:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">one</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">two</li>
</ul>
```

We have BEM patterned classes:

```
<ul class="cars-list">
    <li class="cars-list__car">one</li>
    <li class="cars-list__car">two</li>
</ul>
```

In the scss file for this components we have:

```
.cars-list {
    properties...

    &__car {
        properties...
}
```

Instead of writing my own properties I would love to extend Bootstrap so I can say:

```
.cars-list {
    @extend .list-group;

    &__car {
    @extend .list-group-item;
}
```

My questions are:

- I can include my sass stack into the component .scss so I can extend bootstrap classes BUT then I will be duping all of bootstrap times-the-number components in a given view.
- Will this work with how bootstrap selectors are written?

Comment: Using a framework just to not "rewrite" modals and dropdowns is a bad choise for me. Why "rewrite" dropdown and modals when you can use natives `<select>` and `<dialog>` (using a [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill))?

Just add your style to native elements. You don't need to built custom elements if you are not adding functionalities..